# How to dynamically unregister IntegrationFlow of IntegrationFlowContext if Feed inbound adapter throw an exception?

Tags: rss, spring-integration

I inserted some feeds in a MongoDB collection.

In my Spring Integration application, I use MongoDB inbound adapter to read periodically the feeds collection and check if a feed is enabled or not.

If a fedd is enabled and not yet in the IntegrationFlowContext, I register it.

Once a feed IntegrationFlow is created, it reads the feed periodically to extract articles.

The problem is, if the Feed inbound adapter throw an exception, for example because the URL is not valid anymore, how can I catch this exception (there is no error channel available) and unregister the feed of the IntegrationFlowContext ?

I created a Gist to expose my problem https://gist.github.com/OttoDev/63d31f301bdd777694f4331cab782913

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `errorChannel` to the `poller` to get the exception.

There are two ways to unregister the flow.

1. Keep a reference to the registration and call `destroy()` on it.
2. `context.remove(flowId)` (which is what #1 does)

Comment: Thanks Gary. I think the error channel of the poller is what I need.

Comment: Adding an error channel to the poller works fine. Is there a way to either customize the exception (and its content) thrown to the error channel or to add a new entry in the headers of the message to indicate what feed is causing the exception ?

Comment: You would have to add `.enrichHeaders()` to the feed flow to add a header; then in the error flow; `payload.failedMessage.headers['myHeader']`.

Comment: I tried to add my custom header this way : `IntegrationFlows
  .from(Feed.inboundAdapter(new URL(feedUrl), feedName).metadataStore(metadataStore), e -> e.poller(...).errorChannel(feedErrorQueueChannel)))
  .enrichHeaders(headerEnricherSpec -> headerEnricherSpec.header("feedName", feedName))
  .channel(feedQueueChannel)
  .get());`. But this does not work, my failed message is null. However, `errorMessage.getHeaders()` give me two headers, id and timestamp.

Comment: Don't put code in comments; it's unreadable; edit the question instead. `failedMessage` is null; Oh; right, there is no message yet if the feed is down. The easiest way would be to have an errorChannel flow for each feed and put the enricher there.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to register it dynamically? There is just enough to handle disable/enable via start()/stop() lifecycle control. Anyway the Inbound Channel Adapter can be configured with the `errorChannel` see the second arg of the `IntegrationFlows.from()`.

Comment: Thanks Artem. I need to register feeds dynamically because new  feeds could be added to my MongoDB collection and I want to detect this new feeds periodically. How could I use start and stop methods in my case ?